# WSO2 ESB event, topic and proxy

Tags: events, proxy, wso2-esb

I have an issue which I do not have an idea how to resolve it.

I am trying to call a topic through a proxy using an event. However this never call the proxy subscribed to it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="publishSubscribeTest" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* START METHOD *********************" name="publishSubscribeTest"/>
      </log>

      <event topic="TestTopic"/>

      <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* END METHOD *********************" name="publishSubscribeTest"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <drop/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

The topic has the following details:

`Topic Name: TestTopic
Permissions Details: (Everyone has permission to subscribe and publish)
WS Subscription Details: Another custom proxy in WSO2 has been configured as WS Subscription Details.`

So when first proxy calls the topic, it should call the proxy subscribed to that topic. However it is never called.

This is the proxy called by topic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="proxyCalledByTopic" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* START METHOD *********************" name="proxyCalledByTopic"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

So the log should be something like:

> publishSubscribeTest = ********************* END METHOD *********************
>   proxyCalledByTopic = ********************* START METHOD *********************
>   publishSubscribeTest = ********************* START METHOD *********************

However it is like:

> publishSubscribeTest = ********************* END METHOD *********************
>   publishSubscribeTest = ********************* START METHOD *********************

So I understand that the proxy called by the topic in the subscription is not called.

Any suggestion? Any help?

Thank you,
Pablo

Comment: SOLVED: Installing version 4.9.0, this issue happens just in 4.8.0